# What is the pathname (the directory and file name) of the configuration file used for the DHCP client (not the server!)

Tags: linux, fedora, dhcp, ipv4

(This question refers to the IPv4 client, not the IPv6 client.) 
(Hint: configuration files are kept under the directory `/etc`.)

It is for a school assignment. I have to use `man` pages to find it.
I believe it is the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and I believe it is the dhclient(8) man page, but there is also the dhclient.conf(5) man page. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct.

Both manpages refer to the same thing - one to the DHCP client, and one to its configuration.

I think it will help you to understand if you do some reading on what manpage sections are.